# Remove all hyphens, special characters etc. from string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, special-characters, str-replace

Is there a general used regex that removes **ALL** hyphens, special characters etc., so I will only get letters.

For example a regex containing: ,./<>?;':"|[]{}-=_+1234567890!@#$%^&*()|\ ~` and all of the hyphens and special characters.

(don't know if this is called a regex, but I hope you get the idea)

Comment: Do you only want to get `a-zA-Z` and not even digits?

Comment: regexp as a whitelist: `[a-z]` with the `/i` switch for case-insensitivity, if you only want letters (if you want non-ASCII letters, then say so)

Comment: why don't you try this in `str_replce("/your_removal_list/", "" $str)`

Comment: @FrayneKonok That's mean OP needs to do bunch of `str_replace()`  which isn't as good as `preg_replace()` in this case

Comment: @Chay22, The OP did't mention how much characters he need, So i give that suggestion.

Comment: @FrayneKonok You're right. But, the  **ALL** word seems proven me it has that many for my case :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work :

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", "", $string);
```

if you want to keep numbers, use this one :

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $string);
```

Comment: that seems to remove the letters also, now it shows nothing :p

Comment: `i` switch for case-insensitive

Comment: i switch? what is that?

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen - The `i` switch would be using `$string = preg_replace("/[^a-z]+/i", "", $string);` (note the `i` after the terminating `/` in the regexp, which indicates "case-insensitive" to the regexp parser

Comment: No "switch" (it is called a modifier) is necessary with `\P{L}`

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get only letters, remove all that are not letters:

```
preg_replace('~\P{L}+~u', '', $input)
```

The `\P{L}` is a Unicode property that matches all characters other than Unicode letters. **See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yQ5dQ9/1).**

If you need to also handle diacritics (i.e. if you need to keep them), use

```
preg_replace('~[^\p{M}\p{L}]+~u', '', $input)
```

where `\p{M}` matches any diacritic symbol, and `[^\p{M}\p{L}]+` matches 1 or more characters other than letters and diacritics.

**See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/yQ5dQ9/2)**.

Comment: Works almost, but it does not remove - hyphens

Comment: still does not remove / - and _

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen: You should show your code as it handles something before the regex comes into play. [The regex removes all symbols other than letters](https://regex101.com/r/hU6rO6/1)